# Split Big Image in PDF created using iText

Tags: image, pdf, split, itext

I have a PDF which displays a dynamic image (Chart created with JFreeChart). The chart is dynamic and hence can span across multiple pages. But I'm unable to split image across pages. I tried splitLate(false) as well. Please suggest solutions / ideas / workaround.

Ciao,
SKR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found two ways to solve the issue.

1. Split the generated image using some image splitting algorithm. Place each of the split images in a new document page.
      **Pros** : Simple
   **Cons** : The chart may be split in the middle of a bar.
2. Send partial inputs to the Chart Creator Method and create multiple charts. Place each of the partial input charts in a new page.
      **Pros** : Perfect charts.
   **Cons** : Little bit more effort than the 1st solution.